# Make uppercase on the first letter of user input C#

Tags: c#, arrays, toupper

I am trying to make an easy and clean solution for my code to recieve a name from input from user and printing it out with uppercase on the first letter only. I have tried for a long time but cannot come to a solution, I am now trying to make it by using an array and selecting the first letter but i get this error message *"No overload for method 'ToUpper' takes 0 arguments"*

**
fn[0].ToUpper()** ?

[IMAGE OF MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mznZ4.png)

```
   static void Introduce()
    {
        Console.Write("Hi! What is your first name?");
        fn = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Hi! What is your last name?");
        ln = Console.ReadLine();


        name = fn[0].ToUpper() + " " + ln[0].ToUpper();

        Console.WriteLine(name);

    }
```

Would really appriciate any help!

Using .ToUpper and making it into an array and selecting the first letter [0] but with an error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple way with `ToUpper`:

```
string firstName = char.ToUpper(fn[0]) + fn.Substring(1);
string lastName = char.ToUpper(ln[0]) + ln.Substring(1);
```

We first use `char.ToUpper` method to convert the first letter of the first name and last name to uppercase. And then we use `Substring` method to get the remaining part of the name, starting from index 1, and concatenate this 2 strings with `+` operator.

You can also use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) and [ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) for string:

```
string firstName = $"{char.ToUpper(fn[0])}{fn[1..]}";
string lastName = $"{char.ToUpper(ln[0])}{ln[1..]}";
```